# Extension of analytic function to the boundary of its domain using non-tangential limits

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the open unit disk of the complex plane and let $f : \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Assume that $f$ has non-tangential limits on a dense set on $\partial\mathbb{D}$ such that the values can be extended to a continuous function on $\partial\mathbb{D}$. Is it enough to deduce that $f$ can be extended to a continuous function on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ that is analytic on its interior?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Enough for what?

Comment: @TheOscillator I think "Is it" should be "Is this"

Answer (score 3):

Here's a counterexample: Let $E\subset \partial\mathbb D$ be a dense subset of measure $0.$ Then there exists a positive harmonic function $u$ on $\mathbb D$ such that

$$\tag 1 \lim_{z\to \zeta,z\in \mathbb D}u(z)=\infty$$

for each $\zeta\in E.$*

Using $(1),$ let $v$ be a harmonic conjugate of  $u.$ Set $f=e^{-(u+iv)}.$ Then

$$\lim_{z\to \zeta,z\in \mathbb D}f(z)=0$$

for each $\zeta\in E.$ Note that these limits allow full approach within the disc, not just nontangential approach.

I'll leave the verification that this $f$ is indeed a counterexample. But ask if you have questions.

*See Exercise 18, Chapter 6, Harmonic Function Theory by Axler, Bourdon, and Ramey  https://www.axler.net/HFT.pdf

Comment: nice counterexample - By Privalov Theorem the result holds when the set in question has non-zero measure on the circle regardless of its density